# Got Error " Library routine called out of sequence " when use Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore + Xamarin froms

Tags: xamarin, azure-mobile-services, azure-sql-database

I have got following Error " Library routine called out of sequence "
when used Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore.

Please Help me.

Thanks

Comment: What operation you do with SQLite cause the error? Would you like to [enable offline sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-offline-data) for Xamarin.Forms mobile app?

Comment: I have the same issue, if I use offline sync with some related tables.. Other related tables works good..

Comment: My workaround is, that I call PullAsync more than once.. which a delay from round about 3 seconds